# responsive image with text on the right using clearfix

Tags: html, css, clearfix, responsiveness

I'm trying to create a responsive image at the right of the page (from top to bottom) and trying to put text at the right of the image in the space that is leftover but it doens't seem to work. I've googled and found a solution called clearfix. It works but but when a window becomes to small, the text doesn't have an overflow.

Is ther e a way to make the text on the right of the image scolable while the image itself stays responsive?

**CSS**

```
body {


margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.site_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.site_wrapper > #img_golf {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
.main {
    position:relative;
    top: 2%;
    bottom: 0; 
    overflow-y: scroll
}
#main div { min-height: 100% }
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="site_wrapper">

<img src="images/achtergrond_home.jpg" />    

    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="main">
        Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean fixed position instead of responsive ?

Comment: I mean that the image itself has to repond to the window form top to bottom. So when I change my browserwindow size.

Comment: Also, I saw I forgot to put an id on the img in the code above, id="img_golf". Sorry about that

Comment: Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7ddqd6z/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="half-screen image" style="background-image:url('http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/5217a4036bb3f73e7c000013/pga-tour-golfer-hit-a-ball-off-of-a-bridge-to-within-two-feet-of-the-hole.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="half-screen text">
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.half-screen{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.image{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: Thnks for your reply. Almost! It was my intention to only let the text scroll. The image has to stay in place. Is that possible?

Comment: add this to your css:
.text{ overflow-y: auto; }

Comment: Ok this comes close, thnx. You've used the image as a background but I have a designed an image that has to be seen in whole, so height:100%; if you know what I mean. So I can't prodict what the width of the image will be when I make my screen larger.